# CDN подключается к сайту через HTTP (без SSL), безопасно ли это?

Tags: http, безопасность, https, cdn

Настраиваю один сервис CDN для сайта. Сервис требует, чтобы сайт отвечал ему по HTTP (а не по HTTPS). При этом отдачу посетителю через HTTPS сервис CDN обеспечивает сам.

Понятно, что трафик от посетителя до CDN будет шифрованным, но меня беспокоит, что в какой-то момент трафик будет открытым, пусть это только между CDN и хостингом. Безопасно ли это? Я раньше не сталкивался с CDN и не знаю, нормально ли такое требование от сервиса CDN?

Answer (score 0):

Требование вполне себе нормальное. Всё зависит от того, как вы настроите CDN. Но в любом случае, вероятность к MITM-атакам исключать нельзя.

[When HTTPS Meets CDN: A Case of Authenti
cation in Delegated Service](http://netsec.ccert.edu.cn/duanhx/files/2014/05/httpsincdn.pdf)